# Как работают Signals and Slots в PyQt?

Tags: python, ооп, gui, pyqt, сигналы-слоты

У меня есть несколько вопросов насчет принципов работы сигналов в *PyQt*.

Смотрел гайд и столкнулся с таким вопросом: 
"У меня есть функция, которая выполняет действие  при выборе определенного `QMenuBar`, которая просто выводит на экран его название".

В видео используется функция с аргументами `self` и **`q`**.

Почему, не передавая никаких аргументов в данную функцию мы можем воспользоваться **`q`** и вывести на экран текст из `menubar`?

И еще, для кнопок использовал `sender()`, чтобы также по названию проверить, что за кнопка. 
Когда использую `sender()` для `menubar`, то программа закрывается.

Вот пример кода:

```
...    

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    bar = self.menuBar()
    file = bar.addMenu('File')
    edit = bar.addMenu('Edit')

    save_action = QAction ('Save', self)
    save_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')

    new_action = QAction('New', self)
    new_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')

    quit_action = QAction('Quit', self)
    quit_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')

    find_action = QAction ('Find...', self)

    replace_action = QAction ('Replace...',self)

    file.addAction(new_action)
    file.addAction(save_action)
    file.addAction(quit_action)
    find_menu = edit.addMenu('Find')
    find_menu.addAction(find_action)
    find_menu.addAction(replace_action)

    quit_action.triggered.connect(self.quit_trigger)
    file.triggered.connect(self.selected)

def quit_trigger(self):
    qApp.quit()

def selected (self,q):
    print(q.text() + ' selected')
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Почему, не передавая никаких аргументов в данную функцию мы можем воспользоваться q**

Signals и Slots это бызовые поняти PyQt, в Python такого нет.

Смотрим строку: `file.triggered.connect(self.selected)`

```
где: 
    file      - `QtWidgets.QMenu object`;
    triggered - Этот сигнал `QMenuBar::triggered(QAction *action)`
                испускается, когда действие в меню, принадлежащем этой строке меню, 
                запускается в результате щелчка мышью; 
                `action` - это действие, которое вызвало испускание сигнала.
                Обычно вы подключаете каждое действие меню к одному слоту, 
                используя `QAction :: triggered()`, но иногда вам может понадобиться 
                подключить несколько элементов к одному слоту 
                (чаще всего, если пользователь выбирает из массива). 
                Этот сигнал полезен в таких случаях.
    connect(self.selected) - присоединяем сигнал к слоту `self.selected`.
```

Здесь мы присоединяем сигнал `triggered` принадлежащий `file -> QtWidgets.QMenu object` 
к слоту `self.selected`.

**Отправитель**(·file -> QtWidgets.QMenu·) – объект, который посылает сигнал. 
Для определения какой именно виджет является отправителем сигнала имеет метод sender().

**Получатель**(self.selected) – объект, который получает сигнал.

**Слот**(def selected (self, q): ...) – это метод, который реагирует на сигнал.

Т.е. мы имеем встроенный сигнал `triggered` объекта `QMenu`, который автоматически 
в результате щелчка мышью по одному из Меню('File') испускается действие(`action`),
которое передается в слот(`def selected (self, q): ...`)

Некоторые комментарии см. в тексте примера, а также обратите внимание на выводы принтов.

Когда вы начнете писать свои привязки Сигналов и Слотов вам понадобится Четыре действия:

```
- создать сигнал ->  mySignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(...)
- послать сигнал ->  self.mySignal.emit(...)
- сделать привязку Сигнала и Слота -> widget.mySignal.connect(self.Slot)
- создать слот -> def Slot(self, ...): ...
```

В вашем примере первые два действия встроены в объект `QMenu`

Дополнительную информацию см.  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

---

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        bar = self.menuBar()
        print("\n\tbar ->{}, bar.sender ->{}".format(bar, bar.sender()))    # +++

        file = bar.addMenu('File')
        edit = bar.addMenu('Edit')

        save_action = QAction ('Save', self)
        save_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        new_action = QAction('New', self)
        new_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        quit_action = QAction('Quit', self)
        quit_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')

        file.addAction(new_action)
        file.addAction(save_action)
        file.addAction(quit_action)        

        find_action = QAction ('Find...', self)
        replace_action = QAction ('Replace...',self)
        find_menu = edit.addMenu('Find')
        find_menu.addAction(find_action)
        find_menu.addAction(replace_action)

        # Обычно вы подключаете каждое действие меню к одному слоту, 
        # используя `QAction :: triggered()`
        quit_action.triggered.connect(self.quit_trigger)

        # но иногда вам может понадобиться подключить несколько элементов
        # к одному слоту 
        file.triggered.connect(self.selected)


# +++   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        print("""
            file          ->`{}`, 
            file.title    ->`{}`,
            file.sender() ->`{}`
            """.format(file, file.title(), file.sender()))           
        self.bar_2  = bar                                    
        self.file_2 = file                                   
        print("-- file_2-> {}, file_2.sender()->{}".format(self.file_2, self.file_2.sender()))        
# +++   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 

    def quit_trigger(self):
        qApp.quit()

    def selected (self, q):
        print("\n\t", q.text() + ' selected')

# +++   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  
        print("\t q -->> ", q)

        print("\tbar_2 -> {} <- {}".format(self.bar_2.sender().title(), self.bar_2.sender()))
        print("\tfile_2-> {} <- {}".format(self.file_2.sender().text(), self.file_2.sender()))
# +++   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('Как работают Signals and Slots в PyQt')
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon('im.png'))
    w.resize(600, 450)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В метод `connect` вы передаёте ссылку на метод `quit_trigger`. При вызове `quit_trigger` по этой ссылке, интерпретатор Python автоматически передаст ссылку на экземпляр класса, в котором определён метод - `self`, а графическая библиотека Qt автоматически передаст ссылку на экземпляр виджета, с которым произошло событие - `q`.

Пример №1:

```
class SomeClass:
    def method(self):
        print(self.name)


# Создаём два объекта    
a = SomeClass()
b = SomeClass()
# и присваиваем им имена
a.name = 'Объект A'
b.name = 'Объект Б'

# Выводим имя объекта a, явно передавая ссылку на него
SomeClass.method(a)
# Пользуемся услугами Python для вывода имени объекта b
b.method()
```

Пример №2:

```
# Грубый "макет" меню
class MenuItem:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def connect(self, f):
        self.callback = f

    def trigger(self):
        self.callback(self)


# Примитивный обработчик
def some_function(q):
    print('Кто-то нажал на ' + q.name)


# Создаём элемент меню
file_menu = MenuItem('File')
# Подключаем к нему обработчик
file_menu.connect(some_function)
# Эмулируем возникновение события клика
file_menu.trigger()
```