# Как реализовать ползунок, контролирующий момент воспроизведения mp3-файла?(PyQt 5, Python 3)

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qmediaplayer, qslider

Я видел некоторые примеры, где создавали `QSlider`, который был привязан к `QMediaPlayer`. Но эти примеры были осложнены различными дополнительными функциями, из-за чего мне было очень тяжело понять устройство самого ползунка.

Я бы хотел создать простой ползунок, который мог бы контролировать момент воспроизведения аудиофайла. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как его можно сделать?

Сейчас мой код может только воспроизводить и ставить на паузу файлы, пути к которым хранит словарь `self.dict`:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.dict = {
            '1.Papercut.mp3': [], 
            '13.Numb.mp3': []
        }

        self.song = ''

        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.qsl = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.qsl.sliderMoved[int].connect(self.SetPlayPosition)
        self.box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)   

        for line, song in enumerate(self.dict):
            play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', clicked=lambda song=song: self.play(song))

            pause_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Pause', clicked=self.pause, enabled=False)

            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(song)
            self.box.addWidget(play_btn, line, 0)
            self.box.addWidget(pause_btn, line, 1)
            self.box.addWidget(label, line, 2)

            self.dict[song].append(play_btn)
            self.dict[song].append(pause_btn)

        self.box.addWidget(self.qsl, 2, 0)

    def SetPlayPosition(self):
        self.player.setPosition(self.qsl.value())

    # Воспроизведение
    def play(self, song):
        if self.player.isAudioAvailable() == False:
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
            self.dict[song][1].setEnabled(True)
            self.song = song

        if self.song == song:
            pass
        else:
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
            self.dict[self.song][1].setEnabled(False)
            self.dict[song][1].setEnabled(True)
            self.song = song

        self.player.play()

    # Пауза
    def pause(self):
        self.player.pause()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('MP3-player, PyQt5')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, все подробности здесь https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html
и здесь  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qslider.html

Я отметил для вас строки, в которые внесены изменения.

```
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.dict = {
            'bibi.mp3': [], 
            'D:/_Qt/EXE/Mp3/new_build/QThread_mp3/img/zvuki_prirody.mp3': []
        }
        self.song = ''

        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        # [signal]void QMediaPlayer::stateChanged(QMediaPlayer::State state)           # +++
        self.player.stateChanged.connect(self.playerState)                             # +++   !!!

        self.qsl = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.qsl.sliderMoved[int].connect(self.SetPlayPosition)
        self.qsl.sliderReleased.connect(self.slider_released)                          # +++   !!!

        self.box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)   

        for line, song in enumerate(self.dict):            # !!!    vv                               # vvvv             
            play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', clicked=lambda ch, song=song: self.play(song))  # + ch, !!!

            pause_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Pause', clicked=self.pause, enabled=False)

            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(song)
            self.box.addWidget(play_btn, line, 0)
            self.box.addWidget(pause_btn, line, 1)
            self.box.addWidget(label, line, 2)

            self.dict[song].append(play_btn)
            self.dict[song].append(pause_btn)

        self.box.addWidget(self.qsl, 2, 0, 1, 3)                                                # + , 1, 3

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      
        self.Play_Pause = True
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.PlayMode)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def PlayMode(self):
        if self.Play_Pause==False:
            self.qsl.setMinimum(0)
            self.qsl.setMaximum(self.player.duration())
            self.qsl.setValue(self.qsl.value() + 1000)

    def slider_released(self):
#        print(f'slider_released ->> {self.qsl.value()}')                  # !!!
        self.player.setPosition(self.qsl.value())                          # !!!
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def SetPlayPosition(self, val):
        pass
#?        self.player.setPosition(self.qsl.value())  # см. выше
#        print(val)                                                        # !!!

    # Воспроизведение
    def play(self, song):
        if self.player.isAudioAvailable() == False:
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
            self.dict[song][1].setEnabled(True)
            self.song = song

        if self.song == song:
            pass
        else:
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
            self.dict[self.song][1].setEnabled(False)
            self.dict[song][1].setEnabled(True)
            self.song = song

        self.player.play()
        self.Play_Pause=False                                                            # +++

    # Пауза
    def pause(self):
        self.player.pause()
        self.Play_Pause=True                                                             # +++

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      
    def playerState(self, state):
        if state == 0:
#            self.qsl.setValue(0)
            self.Play_Pause=True
            self.qsl.setSliderPosition(0)
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('MP3-player, PyQt5')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное, буду разбирать код:)

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, зачем в коде создается таймер?

Comment: @MAXIM045   Это позволяет перемещать `slider handle`  вдоль горизонтальной 
канавки, т.е. когда вы нажали кнопку 'Play' вы видите движение бегунка слайдера. 
Добавьте в конце метода `PlayMode` строку  `print(self.qsl.value())` и смотрите что происходит.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Опять я вас мучаю:( Появился очередной вопрос - где метод `playerState` берет аргумент `state`? Наверное, постоянно глупые вещи спрашиваю, но, потратив достаточно много времени, я так и не смог разобраться

Comment: @MAXIM045  Одной из ключевых особенностей Qt является использование сигналов и слотов для связи между объектами.  https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html  Этот надо выучить как таблицу умножения, иначе никак.  https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#defining-new-signals-with-pyqtsignal

Comment: @MAXIM045 строка `self.player.stateChanged.connect(self.playerState)` 
эквивалентна `self.player.stateChanged[QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.State].connect(self.playerState)` 
Читать здесь https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#stateChanged и  здесь https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#State-enum

Comment: Большое вам спасибо:)

Comment: @MAXIM045 я уже пытался объяснить это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/953682/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-signals-and-slots-%d0%b2-pyqt/953776#953776 почитайте может будет полезно.   THE END !